# how to add data to existing database from another database?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i'm working with my friend on a project and we have the same database but in different devices..so he has data in the database and i have another data in my database and when we export his database and import it to my database, all the data in my DB is delete it and keep only his data ..
so my question is **how to export my friend database and import it to mine without deleting my data**..?

note: 
we are using phpmyadmin ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Assuming you have your DDL(tables etc) in sync duplicates may be an issue for you. You may have duplicates because you and your friend have entered the same data or if you import your friends data more than once. You might consider dumping your data truncating all tables , then loading your data and loading your friends data using insert on duplicate key (or some other strategy) to avoid duplicates with your data.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do it:

First Way : you can create scripts for same like follows:

1. Right-click the database > Tasks > Generate Scripts.
2. Click Next
3. Leave Script all objects in the selected database unchecked and click Next
4. Under choose script options, set Include if NOT EXISTS to True and set Script Data to True and click Next
5. Check Tables
6. Select All and click Next
7. Script to File and then open this file in the new Database as a sql script.

2nd Way: you can user SQLMerger for same. (Easies way)

Comment: i don't see your steps in my panel it seems to be this in sql management studio but any way i search for the box that says "NOT EXISTS" and i made it true.. after that i tried to add the data it works fine with tables but it doesn't work with relationship table it delete all the data...can you give my any solution?... and thanks any way..

Comment: You can import table data of your friend's database into your database, but i would suggest you to set database on server and use same database. because when you both use different database and merge it after, it might create issues with primary key data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following command which will only create a dump of mysql data without any create info. What i am assuming you are creating a dump of complete database which is recreating a database and tables with your friends data.

> mysqldump --no-create-info

Answer (score -1):

MAKE A C# PROGRAM AND INSERT ALL DATA USING PROGRAM..